# Почему border не отображается

Tags: html, css, border

```css
#content{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 80%;
            background: 5px solid red;
        }
        .kategoriya {

            float: left;
            width: 29%;
            height: 80%;
            background: 1px solid red;
        }
        .galereya{
            float: right;
            width: 100%;
            height: 80%;
            background: 1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
  <div id="content">
<div class="kategoriya">
    <p></p>
</div>
<div class="galereya"></div>
```

Comment: background? может border нужно написать?

Comment: обе red. background: 5px solid red; - а такого вобще не бывает

Answer (score 2):

- По ответу `TOS` преобразовал `background:5px solid red` в `border`
- Добавил блокам `background:#color;`
- Не был закрыт один из тегов `<div>`

```css
#content{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 5px solid red;
     background:#D5D5D5;
     
   
        }
        .kategoriya {
         position: absolute;
            bottom:0%;
   width: 100%;
            height: 20%;
            border: 1px solid red;
   background:yellowgreen;
        }
        .galereya{
            position: absolute; 
   top:40%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 40%;
            border: 1px solid red;
   background:skyblue;
        }
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<div class="kategoriya">
    <p></p>
</div>
<div class="galereya"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что не `background: 5px solid red;`, а `border:5px solid red;`